# C++ dll seems not to work correctly in .NET

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I have c++ dll in my .NET project. Methods from dll are imported as shown below

```
    private const string LibName = "dll_name.dll";

    [DllImport(LibName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public extern static void Method1(double[] _params, UInt32 len);

    [DllImport(LibName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public extern static double Method2(Int32 x, Int32 y);
```

For the first time it worked well. But then I discovered, when I build dll from Visual Studio 2012 or higher, program can't find dll and throws an exception "File not found". But when I build the same dll from the same project in VS 2010 there is no problem. I don't think that toolchain version can make such a big difference.
How can I make it work from newer versions of VS?

Comment: Where is the DLL located?  Is it somewhere in your system path or local to the project?

Comment: what @DStanley said, or just stick in the same directory as the executable trying to pinvoke into it.

Comment: Dll is in the same directory with executable

Comment: It tells you "File not found", possibly the most common error message there is.  It doesn't tell you *what* file wasn't found.  It doesn't have to be "dll_name.dll", it could also be a DLL that it needs, like the CRT.  Nor does it tell you *where* it looked for the file.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to remove any doubt, you'll see it searching for a file and not finding it.

Comment: This also feels like a c runtime side-by-side issue.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for great utility, btw you was right, it searched for new redistributable c++ package. If you'd like post an answer, i will mark it as a solution

Comment: There were a lot of changes for VS2013 toolset(120), so the problem may not be trivial but for me it looks like some permission problems. Did you try to debug the application under Admin rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in comments problem was in different version of VS toolset. If you use new VS you'll need new MSVCredist as well.